TelecomManager.addNewIncomingCall fails when a call is already ringing
I'm developing a VoIP call app on Android with third party SIP stack.
This app works fine for the most part, but when there is an incoming (and unanswered) call, addNewIncomingCall fails and ConnectionService.onCreateIncomingConnectionFailed is called.
Any ideas of what I'm missing?
Demo code:
in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

...

<service
    android:name=".MyConnectionService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,  arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,
        ), 0)

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MultipleIncomingCallTestTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val helper = remember { MyTelecomHelper(context, context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager) }
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,modifier = modifier
    ){
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val account = if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    return@Button
                }else{
                    helper.initPhoneAccount()
                }
                helper.startIncoming("1234", "User A", account.accountHandle)
            },
            modifier = modifier
        ){
            Text("Incoming Call A")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val account = if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    return@Button
                }else{
                    helper.initPhoneAccount()
                }
                helper.startIncoming("5678", "User B", account.accountHandle)
            },
            modifier = modifier
        ){
            Text("Incoming Call B")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                helper.disconnect("1234")
            },
            modifier = modifier
        ){
            Text("Disconnect Call A")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                helper.disconnect("5678")
            },
            modifier = modifier
        ){
            Text("Disconnect Call B")
        }
    }
}

MyTelecomHelper.kt
class MyTelecomHelper(
    private val context: Context,
    private val telecomManager: TelecomManager
) {

    private val connections = mutableListOf<MyConnection>()
    init{
        MyConnectionService.addConnectionStateChangedListener( object:ConnectionStateChangedListener{
            override fun onStateChanged(state: Int, connection: MyConnection) {
                when(state){
                    Connection.STATE_RINGING->{
                        connections.add(connection)
                    }
                    Connection.STATE_DISCONNECTED->{
                        connections.remove(connection)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun createAccount(context: Context): PhoneAccount {
        val accountHandle = PhoneAccountHandle(
            ComponentName(context, MyConnectionService::class.java),
            context.packageName
        )
        val account = PhoneAccount.builder(accountHandle, "Test Account")
            .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)
            .setSupportedUriSchemes(listOf(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL))
            .build()
        try {
            telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(account)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(this.javaClass.simpleName, e.toString())
        }
        return account
    }
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    private fun findExistingAccount(context: Context): PhoneAccount? {
        val connectionService = ComponentName(
            context,
            MyConnectionService::class.java
        )

        val targetPhoneAccountHandle =
            telecomManager.selfManagedPhoneAccounts.firstOrNull { phoneAccountHandle ->
                phoneAccountHandle.componentName == connectionService
            }
        return telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(targetPhoneAccountHandle)
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    fun initPhoneAccount(): PhoneAccount {
        return findExistingAccount(context) ?: return createAccount(context)
    }

    fun startIncoming(number: String, name: String, accountHandle: PhoneAccountHandle) {
        telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(
            accountHandle,
            Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable(
                    TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS,
                    Bundle().apply {
                        putString("name", name)
                        putString("number", number)
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }

    fun disconnect(number: String) {
        connections.lastOrNull {
            (it.state == Connection.STATE_DIALING
                    || it.state == Connection.STATE_RINGING
                    || it.state == Connection.STATE_ACTIVE
                    || it.state == Connection.STATE_HOLDING)
                    && it.address.schemeSpecificPart == number
        }?.let {
            it.setDisconnected(DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.LOCAL))
            connections.remove(it)
        }
    }
}

MyConnectionService.kt
class MyConnectionService : ConnectionService() {
    override fun onCreateIncomingConnection(
        connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?,
        request: ConnectionRequest?
    ): Connection {
        val bundle = request?.extras?.getBundle(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_EXTRAS)
        val name = bundle?.getString("name")
        val number = bundle?.getString("number")
        val connection = MyConnection(stateChangedListeners).apply {
            setAddress(Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL,number,null), TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED)
            setCallerDisplayName(name, TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED)
            setRinging()
        }
        Log.d(MyConnectionService::class.java.simpleName, "Incoming Connection created.\n" +
                "name = $name\n" +
                "number = $number")
        return connection
    }

    override fun onCreateIncomingConnectionFailed(
        connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?,
        request: ConnectionRequest?
    ) {

        Log.d(MyConnectionService::class.java.simpleName, "Incoming Connection failed.\n" +
                "connectionManagerPhoneAccount = $connectionManagerPhoneAccount\n" +
                "request = $request")
    }
    companion object{
        private val stateChangedListeners = mutableListOf<ConnectionStateChangedListener>()

        fun addConnectionStateChangedListener(listener: ConnectionStateChangedListener) {
            stateChangedListeners.add(listener)
        }

    }
}

MyConnection.kt
interface ConnectionStateChangedListener {
    fun onStateChanged(state: Int, connection: MyConnection)
}

class MyConnection(
    private val stateChangeListeners: MutableList<ConnectionStateChangedListener> = mutableListOf()
) : Connection() {
    init{
        audioModeIsVoip = true
        connectionProperties = PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED
        connectionCapabilities = CAPABILITY_MUTE or CAPABILITY_HOLD or CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD
        setInitializing()
    }

    override fun onStateChanged(state: Int) {
        Log.d(MyConnection::class.java.simpleName, "onStateChanged: $address $state")
        stateChangeListeners.forEach { listener ->
            listener.onStateChanged(state, this)
        }
    }

    override fun onAnswer() {
        super.onAnswer()
        setActive()
    }

    override fun onReject() {
        super.onReject()
        setDisconnected(DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.REJECTED))
    }

    override fun onDisconnect() {
        super.onDisconnect()
        setDisconnected(DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.LOCAL))
    }

    override fun onHold() {
        super.onHold()
        setOnHold()
    }

    override fun onUnhold() {
        super.onUnhold()
        setActive()
    }

    override fun onMuteStateChanged(isMuted: Boolean) {
        super.onMuteStateChanged(isMuted)
    }
}

